# NHibernate's format_sql property (not that) pretty printing

Tags: sql, nhibernate, orm, formatting

Comparing the following output with samples I've seen here at Stack Overflow and over the internet makes me wonder what am I doing wrong, as apparently both the `show_sql` and `format_sql` properties are correctly set?

**Output**

```
NHibernate:
    SELECT
        book0_.Isbn as Isbn0_0_,
        book0_.Title as Title0_0_,
        book0_.Author as Author0_0_,
        book0_.Publisher as Publisher0_0_,
        book0_.Published as Published0_0_,
        book0_.Pages as Pages0_0_,
        book0_.InStock as InStock0_0_,
        book0_.Description as Descript8_0_0_
    FROM
        Books book0_
    WHERE
        book0_.Isbn=@p0;
    @p0 = '0596800959' [Type: String (0)]
```

**Book.cs**

```
public class Book
{
    public string Isbn { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Publisher { get; set; }
    public DateTime Published { get; set; }
    public int? Pages { get; set; }
    public bool InStock { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

**Book.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="Dotnet.Samples.NHibernate"
                   namespace="Dotnet.Samples.NHibernate">
  <class name="Book" table="Books" lazy="false">
    <id name="Isbn" />
    <property name="Title" />
    <property name="Author" />
    <property name="Publisher" />
    <property name="Published" />
    <property name="Pages" />
    <property name="InStock" />
    <property name="Description" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSqlCeDialect</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlServerCeDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=res/Catalog.sdf</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Any advice will be really appreciated. Thanks much in advance.

**UPDATE**

In response to comments I'm adding how the *expected* output should look like (basically a valid SQL statement):

```
NHibernate:
    SELECT
        Isbn,
        Title,
        Author,
        Publisher,
        Published,
        Pages,
        InStock,
        Description
    FROM
        Books
    WHERE
        Isbn = '0596800959'
```

Comment: You want to be able to copy and paste the Query from the Log/Console etc into somthing like SQL Server Management Studio and run the Query with out any modification?  Basically you want an executable version of the SQL that comes out of nhibernate?

Comment: Indeed I mean am I being too ambitious (if you name a property "show_sql" or "format_sql") expecting an output to somewhat comply to regular SQL? I have no reason to expect otherwise.

Comment: Well I guess it basically does comply with regular SQL.  The only thing you have to do is do some editing to either decalre the variables or set the where filter explicitly with the @P0 value. I agree thouhgh, it is a pain, paiticulary if you have a large amount variables like in an Insert Statement.    One comercial product you could try is http://nhprof.com/ which will do what you are after for you.

Comment: I understand what you mean - a pity there isn't a way to hint the POCO class (perhaps via attributes, e.g. `[DataContract]`) about those aliases.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the latest version of NHibernate? This is the original [task](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-1745). This blog implies that it is only supported in [3.0](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arnona/archive/2011/01/19/tip-of-the-day-for-nhibernate-2-show-sql-and-format-sql.aspx).

Comment: I'm currently using version 3.1.0.4000 - not sure if that is the latest but seems fresh enough.

Comment: Do you see any output at all?

Comment: Thanks for the contribution Dmitry although I'm not quite following your question - the output is always the same as the one shown in the original post for the aforementioned assembly version.

Comment: Please provide a link or update the question with expected format.